# Where is the zNod in Zookeeper?

Tags: hbase, apache-zookeeper, apache-omid

Hi I need to know where is ZNode or Zookeeper root directory ?
I'm using Bookkeeper for `Omid Transactional` Support. 
It create a `ledger` diectory in ZNode.

Answer (score 0):

You can use zooinspector(Open Source UI given by Apache for zookeeper) for seeing all the nodes in your zookeeper server.

```
  Each node you create in zookeeper server corresponds to one ZNode .When you 1st run the server then zookeeper have a default node created .i.e (/zookeeper) .
```

Comment: NO !
I found my answer .
$HBASE_HOME/bin/hbase zkcli